IBM db2 - alembic migration
I am trying to run
alembic upgrade head

on my IBM cloud DB2 lite database, but getting
KeyError: ibm_db_sa 

My .venv already has installed the packages ibm_db, ibm_db_sa, and ibm_db_alembi, and the connection-url works when connecting to the DB via sqlalchemy (creating an engine / session). The detailed error tracing is below.
(.venv) PS C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\cell_data_db\db2> alembic upgrade head     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 636, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 626, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 603, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 406, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 586, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\cell_data_db\db2\alembic\env.py", line 82, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\cell_data_db\db2\alembic\env.py", line 71, in run_migrations_online
    context.configure(
  File "<string>", line 8, in configure
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 915, in configure
    self._migration_context = MigrationContext.configure(
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 281, in configure
    return MigrationContext(dialect, connection, opts, environment_context)
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.impl = ddl.DefaultImpl.get_by_dialect(dialect)(
  File "C:\Users\ryan4\GitHub\py-playground\cell-data-db\.venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 132, in get_by_dialect
    return _impls[dialect.name]
KeyError: 'ibm_db_sa'


Need to see the output of pip freeze in your venv.  Also detail if this has ever previously worked for you , for example with different versions or different environments, or using alembic via its API instead of command-line.
